# How to get more specific debug messages and warnings from Aurelia

Tags: debugging, aurelia

After making some coding changes in my project and refreshing the page, I encountered the error below:

[image]

This tells me that the file *loan.js* could not be found. My first thought, then, is to find out what file is trying to make a call to *loan.js*. When I expand any of those errors to view the stack trace, I see system files like:

- system.src.js:xxx
- aurelia-loader-default.js:xxx
- aurelia-templating.js:xxx
- compose.js:xxx
- etc

What *does not* show up is any specific file that would lead me to where my error is. It turns out that in *myFile.js*

[image]

I had forgotten to provide the specific path to *loan.js*

`view-model="loans/loan"`

With multiple view models and views where we make references like the above, how are we expected to debug issues like this when the communication is not specific? Is there some debug, logging error options that I am missing? I'm used to compilers at least providing the last place where the file was attempted to be fetched (causing the 404).

Comment: I'd recommend filing an issue on our `framework` repo regarding this.